# How to implement a popup window with a counter

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to implement a simple popup window in Windows Forms, which will show a simple timer to the user while some slow-running process is executing. The premise is simple; show to the user that something is indeed going on and the application is not frozen. Note that this slow-running process is not a loop, nor is it something that I can tap into.

What I want is a simple popup window, showing some message along the lines "Elapsed time: x seconds", where x is incremented every second.

The basic concept is the following:

```
public void test()
{
    //Some code which does stuff

    //Popup window with counter

    //Perform long running process

    //Close popup window with counter

    //Some other code which does other stuff
}
```

I tried to do it using various ways, including background workers, threads, and of course timers. But I did not manage to make it work as I wanted. And I would prefer not to post any of my code so as not to "lead" the responses to a specific way of doing this.

So what would be the best way to do this work?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
In reply to some comments, since I cannot paste any code in the replies section, I'm editing my original question to accomodate this. One of the implementations that I tried is to spawn the popup window in a separate thread. Although I got no runtime errors, the popup window did not refresh correctly. It indeed poped-up, but no text would show within it, and the counter would not refresh. Here's the code:

```
private void test()
{
    frmProgressTimer ofrmProgressTimer = new frmProgressTimer(); //Instance of popup Form
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task loadTask = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => ProgressTimer(ofrmProgressTimer));
    loadTask.Start();

    //Perform long running process

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task cwt = loadTask.ContinueWith(task => EndProgressTimer(ofrmProgressTimer));
}

private void ProgressTimer(frmProgressTimer ofrmProgressTimer)
{
    ofrmProgressTimer.Show();

    ofrmProgressTimer.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {                
        ofrmProgressTimer.startTimer();
    }));            
}

private void EndProgressTimer(frmProgressTimer ofrmProgressTimer)
{
    ofrmProgressTimer.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ofrmProgressTimer.stopTimer();
        ofrmProgressTimer.Close();
    }));            
}
```

And here's my popup form code:
    public partial class frmProgressTimer : Form
    {
        private int counter = 0;
        private Timer timer1;

```
    public frmProgressTimer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    public void startTimer()
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    public void stopTimer()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter += 1;
        labelText.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know this slow-running process will always take a given amount of time? Instead, you might want to look into using a Background Worker to display a progress bar, that way they'll know it's X% done, rather than (supposedly) 1 minute left, 59 seconds, etc.

[Progress Bar](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar) and [Background Worker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) should help.

Comment: No, unfortunately the time the process takes is unknown and variable. The idea here is not to show how much work is remaining, since I do not know nor can I calculate this in any way. The idea is to show the user that something is going on and the process is not frozen.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I've managed to resolve this in the most simplistic manner. And it works like a charm. Here's how to do it:

```
//Create an instance of the popup window
frmProgressTimer ofrmProgressTimer = new frmProgressTimer();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{                    
    ofrmProgressTimer.startTimer();
    ofrmProgressTimer.ShowDialog();
});
thread.Start();

//Perform long running process

ofrmProgressTimer.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    ofrmProgressTimer.stopTimer();
    ofrmProgressTimer.Close();
}));
```

You can see the code for the popup window in the original post/question, with the only difference that the tick function changes the label text as:

```
labelText.Text = string.Format("Elapsed Time: {0} seconds.", counter.ToString());
```

Thank you to everybody for trying to help me out.

Comment: You should not be creating multiple UI threads for your program.  You should have *one* UI thread and then perform any non-UI work that you have in a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Servy, why should I not be creating multiple UI threads? Note that the PtogressTimer in my solution is a separate form with its own labels and controls. And as a separate thread, it updates its own objects. Why is that inadvisable? How else would this work?

Comment: This is potentially going to lock up your form. It'll prevent closing the application, it'll report as not responding within Task manager, won't respond to any GUI events. It's really bad practice to do this and it'll hurt in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy to do.  Create your dialog, define your long running operation to take place in a non-UI thread when it is shown, add a continuation to that operation which closes the dialog when the task finishes, and then show the dialog.

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.Shown += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoLongRunningWork());
    dialog.Close();
};
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

The code to have the ticking over time should be entirely contained within the dialog, and based on the question it seems you already have that well under control with a simple `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new form, which will pop up, and show a timer. That way it won't be interrupted with all the work on your main form, and the timer will work continuously.

Remember when showing a new from to use newForm.ShowDialog() not newForm.Show(). Your can google the differences

Comment: can you please provide some code snippets for your suggestion? If you look at my edited post, I added code that does this, but it does not work. Yes, I tried the ShowDialog() as well. It's as if the timer does not start at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply start your work on a separate thread. Launch a modal form with your timer output. To display the timer use an actual timer instance set to update every second. When the timer event fire update your dialog.

Finally once you're thread completes close the dialog so your main form is active again.

Comment: I can't check right now on my phone but you may have had issues if you were trying to update the ui from a background thread

Comment: your solution implies that I place my work on the separate thread. But my requirements is that I don't touch my long running process/work. I needed something to "wrap" around it. And this is what I finally got with the solution I provided.

Comment: @GZorpas: Why can you not move your work onto a thread? The solution you've come up with is really bad.

Comment: The reason I cannot move it is because it's code that already existed in the specific application I am working on, and part of the whole process is taken a long time to execute. And the requirements were simple; have some sort of notification for the user so that they know the process is not frozen. If you see in my original post, there are parts of the code before and after the slow running process. Would you mind elaborating as to why my solution is "really bad"?

Comment: @GZorpas: I've elaborated by providing a comment on your own answer. Are you saying that code cannot be moved into another method, or simply wrapped in braces as a threadstart lambda?

Comment: as you can see from my original post, the long running piece of code is part of a procedure, it's not a procedure on its own. And of course it is dependent on code that run before it, and the code that will run after it depends of the long running process. Think of it as the following simple example. There are 30 lines of code in a procedure, and lines 17-20 take a considerably long time to execute. And my need is before line 17 to popup a window with a timer, and after line 20 close that window. This is just to let the user know that indeed something is moving along.

Comment: And yes, I know that I can place the whole procedure in a thread on its own and all that, but that's changing the code considerably, potentially opening the whole applications to a whole bunch of other problems, just so that I can have a popup window. All I wanted was a simple solution. And what I found seems to cover my needs. But I am always open to constructive feedback, especially if there are specific examples that showcase problems.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you need to make it *not closeable* by the user (as if modal dialogs weren't annoying enough) but *closeable* by your code. You could accomplish this by subscribing to the `FormClosing` event of the form. Let's say your popup form's name is `Form2`:

  ```
  private bool mayClose = false;
  public void PerformClose()
  {
      this.mayClose = true;
      this.Close();
  }

  private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
      if (!this.mayClose)
          e.Cancel = true;
  }
  ```
- Create a `Timer`, provide a `Tick` event handler, enable it and set its Interval to 500 milliseconds:

[image]

- Create a label to host your desired text. Let's call it `label1`.
- Within and surrounding your `Tick` event handler do something like this:

  ```
  private DateTime appearedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int seconds = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - this.appearedAt).TotalSeconds;
      this.label1.Text = string.Format(@"Ellapsed seconds: {0}", seconds);
  }
  ```
- Make sure your long running process is happening on a background thread, not on the GUI thread.
  Say your long running process can be thought of as the execution of a method called `MyProcess`.
  If that is the case, then you need to call that method from a secondary thread.

  ```
  // PLACE 1: GUI thread right here
  Thread thread = new Thread(() => 
  {
      // PLACE 2: this place will be reached by the secondary thread almost instantly
      MyProcess();
      // PLACE 3: this place will be reached by the secondary thread
      // after the long running process has finished
  });
  thread.Start();
  // PLACE 4: this place will be reached by the GUI thread almost instantly
  ```
- Show the form right before the long running process starts. This can be done in any of the 2 places (marked in the previous section of code) called `PLACE1` or `PLACE2`. If you do it in `PLACE2` you **will have to** marshal a call back to the GUI thread in order to be able to interact with the WinForms framework safely. Why am I bringing this up ? It's because maybe the long running process is not started from within the GUI thread at all and you **absolutely need to do this**.
- Close the form right after the long running process finishes. This can be done only in `PLACE3` and you absolutely need to marshal a call.
- To wrap the earlier 2 bullets and the answer, you could do this:

  ```
  private void DoIt()
  {
      Form2 form2 = new Form2();
      Action showIt = () => form2.Show();
      Action closeIt = () => form2.PerformClose();

      // PLACE 1: GUI thread right here
      Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
      {
          form2.BeginInvoke(showIt);
          // PLACE 2: this place will be reached by the secondary thread almost instantly
          MyProcess();

          form2.BeginInvoke(closeIt);

          // PLACE 3: this place will be reached by the secondary thread
          // after the long running process has finished
      });
      thread.Start();
      // PLACE 4: this place will be reached by the GUI thread almost instantly
  }
  ```

Comment: @sallushan Please post an answer and explain why that would be a better idea. I'm not saying that it isn't but a clear view about __what is happening__, what we want to accomplish and using smaller granularity is **WAY MORE** pedagogical and effective than teaching frameworks, classes and traditional practices.

Comment: @Eduard Dumitru, one issue that I see with your code is PLACE 4. Since this is reached by the GUI thread almost instantly, it means that any code after this point that is dependent on MyProcess() would fail. This is the reason why I prefer to have the popup window in a thread, rather that MyProcess()

Comment: PLACE 4 is unavoidable. It simply exists. Whether you place code which depends on MyProcess() or not in PLACE 4 is up to you. That is why I pointed it out. You should marshal logic back to the UI thread, from PLACE 3, by means of `Control.BeginInvoke`. Would you have preferred that the method `DoIt` not finish until the `MyProcess()` invocation finished ? You could basically do a while (notFinished) loop feeding the message pump with `Application.DoEvents` calls but leaving aside the fact that it's a gray area, the general effect is the same !